# Make two foreignkey unique on same model

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model like this:

```
class Connection(models.Model):
    start = models.ForeignKey(
        'Point',
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        related_name='start_point',
    )
    end = models.ForeignKey(
        'Point',
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        related_name='end_point',
    )
    length = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=3,
        decimal_places=1,
    )
```

What's the best way to make sure 'start' and 'end' points are not the same? Is there only the form validation method?

Answer (score 0):

You should check about Database Normalization. 
Because you need only 1 item which has a Foreign Key to Point. In your model, it is *neither start nor end* but another one. For example try this:

```
class Connection(models.Model):
connection = models.ForeignKey('Point', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='connection')
start-date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
end-date = DateField()
```

I thought that your "start" and "end" might be about Date issues, that's why I have also updated them. If my assumption is correct, then you can check for more about Django DateField or DateTimeField.

Comment: Points are not dates, they are point names in a graph. Connections are segments between two points. Something like Vertex and Edges in http://www.bogotobogo.com/python/python_Dijkstras_Shortest_Path_Algorithm.php

Comment: So, I got your question wrong. You can check it via an 'if' and raise an Validation Error in your model, like : if start == end:
            raise ValidationError("You cannot keep the two numbers same")
You can even do it within your template within {% if blabla in blablas %} {{blabla_start}} {% endif %} on django but the model one is the precise / the best one.